# .net maui mac catalyst app how to specify INSTALL_PATH when app is packed

Tags: .net, maui, mac-catalyst

I use this command to build .net maui mac catalyst .pkg

`dotnet publish -f net8.0-maccatalyst -c Release -p:MtouchLink=SdkOnly -p:CreatePackage=true -p:EnableCodeSigning=true -p:EnablePackageSigning=true -p:CodesignKey="Apple Distribution: Eigil Krogh (4657....)" -p:CodesignProvision="ChronoWiz Profile App Store MAC" -p:CodesignEntitlements="Platforms\MacCatalyst\Entitlements.Release.plist" -p:PackageSigningKey="3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Eigil Krogh (4657....)"`

As can be seen `CreatePackage=true` and a .pkg is created.

QUESTION:
How / where do I specify the `INSTALL_PATH` where the .app is installed when the user dobbel clicks the .pkg. It is normally `Applications`, but where do I specify that ?

Searched for the solution.

To get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on the pkg file and install it on the current folder. However, if it's a published pkg is for AppStore, after publishing it to Appstore, it only can be in Applications. Therefore, you can't change the `INSTALL_PATH` where the .app is installed.

Comment: I did not know that an install path already was includedd. I did not want to change it from /Applications. After a couple of tries it turns out that the app actually is installed in /Applications.

Comment: @EigilKroghSorensen Thanks for your response, is the published pkg for AppStore?

Comment: Yes (and I previously had trouble Wirth them reg. path

Comment: @EigilKroghSorensen Thanks for the update, if it's published for AppStore, you can't change the INSTALL_PATH where the .app is installed as I said in the post answer. You can also check the official docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-8.0